# Android - Use ADB without developer options

Tags: android, batch-file, deployment, adb

I have a dumb question : is it possible run adb with devices without developer options enabled ?

I want to deploy an app on multiple devices by a batch script, but currently i need to enable developer options and i don't want have to do this.

If it's possible how should i do this ?

Here there is my batch script :

```
@echo off
echo START

for /F %%A in ('adb devices ^|findstr /i /r "device" ^|findstr /i /v "list"') do (
    echo Installing APK to : %%A
    if %%A neq "" (
        adb -s %%A install %1
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: *If it's possible* no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

There is no standard and universal way to do what you want.

Long answer:

It depends. Many manufacturers implement their own proprietary interfaces which could be used to achieve goals similar to yours. For example connecting such device via special USB cable (with specific ID pin) would force that device to enumerate an additional USB interface. That interface could be used for sending special commands (in your case to switch the *USB Debugging* on) to the device. But the discussion of such proprietary information does not belong to SO.